# How to show date in 13-digit Unix Timestamp format in JSpreadSheet?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unix-timestamp

I have data, which contains date. It is saved in Unix Timestamp format. I am looking for a way, how to display this data in JSpreadSheet ("jspreadsheet-ce") so, that it looks like date (YYYY/MM/DD e.g.). Now it is just 13-digit number, which looks awful.

I tried to set the column type to DATE (nothing changed) and to CALENDAR (data did not show). I also tried to set dateFormat, but nothing changed.

Is there any way, how to set the format only in the colums? Without the forEach ? Something as shown in the picture?
[Code screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwy3P.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming your Unix Timestamps are stored in the `timestamp` column
const data = [
  { timestamp: 1629889200 },
  { timestamp: 1630158600 },
  
];


data.forEach(item => {
  item.formattedDate = new Date(item.timestamp * 1000).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: '2-digit',
    day: '2-digit'
  });
});


//Display in JSpreadSheet:
jspreadsheet(document.getElementById('spreadsheet'), {
  data: data,
  columns: [
    // ... other columns
    {
      title: 'Formatted Date',
      data: 'formattedDate'
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: sorry about the comment ... I thought this was the question :p didn't realise the OP didn't post any code - however this would produce the wrong format date (i.e mm/dd/yyyy - which is NEVER the right format for a date)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).